# How to substitute NA by space in this situation?

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
>Mydata
 SampleID  mean      sd      
   F1      NA        NA       
   F2    215.7400 1.5881646 
   F3      NA        NA        
   F4      NA        NA        
   F5      NA        NA
```

I use the following code to round the numerical variable 'mean' and 'sd':

```
mydata$mean<-format(round(mydata$mean,2),nsmall=2)
mydata$sd<-format(round(mydata$sd,2),nsmall=2)
```

And it becomes like this:

```
>mydata
  Sample.ID  mean   sd       
      F1     NA     NA        
      F2   215.74  1.59 
      F3     NA     NA        
      F4     NA     NA     
> summary(mydata)
     mean              sd          
   Length:48          Length:48         
   Class :character   Class :character  
   Mode  :character   Mode  :character
```

I want to replace the NA with space, then I trid several methods, but the NA are still there...

```
> mydata[is.na(mydata)]<-""
>mydata
  Sample.ID  mean   sd       
      F1     NA     NA        
      F2   215.74  1.59 
      F3     NA     NA        
      F4     NA     NA
```

or

```
>mydata[mydata=="NA"]<-""
>mydata
  Sample.ID  mean   sd       
      F1     NA     NA        
      F2   215.74  1.59 
      F3     NA     NA        
      F4     NA     NA
```

I guess it is because the columns which contain "NA' here are characters, so I can't replace all the NAs? Any body know how to replace the character NAs with space?

So appreciate!

Comment: Despite the less than ideal solution posted, I don't see why your code snippets won't work. `is.na()` will work on both `class(character) <NA>` and `class(numeric) NA`

Comment: @Vlo Thank you, I am also very confused why it doesn't work here...And the NAs in character variables 'mean' and 'sd' are not shown as <NA>, they are shown as NA......Is there anything related to length?.....

Comment: @Vlo Another thing is ,before I use the format function to round the variables (here mean and sd are all numeric variables), the "mydata[is.na(mydata)]<-""" works well....So I am guessing something is wrong with character variables....

Comment: Can you check if there is leading/lagging spaces for NA assuming that the NA is character

Comment: @akrun I think there is leading spaces, and that might be the problem.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`.

```
blank.format <- function(x) {
    ifelse(is.na(x), "", format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2))
}

Mydata <- transform(Mydata, mean = blank.format(mean),
                            sd = blank.format(sd))
```

Or if you prefer,

```
Mydata$mean <- ifelse(is.na(Mydata$mean), "", format(round(Mydata$mean, 2), nsmall = 2))
Mydata$sd <- ifelse(is.na(Mydata$sd), "", format(round(Mydata$sd, 2), nsmall = 2))
```

Either way, your data frame will now look like this:

```
Mydata
#   SampleID   mean   sd
# 1       F1            
# 2       F2 215.74 1.59
# 3       F3            
# 4       F4            
# 5       F5            

str(Mydata)
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ SampleID: chr  "F1" "F2" "F3" "F4" ...
#  $ mean    : chr  "" "215.74" "" "" ...
#  $ sd      : chr  "" "1.59" "" "" ...
```

This tests for `NA` while the value is still numeric. If it's `NA`, make the new variable blank, otherwise format as desired.

Comment: This answer is awesome! I need make it blamk when it is still numeric variables!!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NA are converted to strings " NA" when using `format`. So, first of all set the parameter `trim=TRUE` to avoid the first space (from the help: if `trim=FALSE`, logical, numeric and complex values are right-justified to a common width: if TRUE the leading blanks for justification are suppressed.).
So doing now you still have "NA" strings, so your condition to replace them with spaces should be

```
mydata$mean[mydata$mean=="NA"]<-""
mydata$sd[mydata$sd=="NA"]<-""
```